# submit webiste's or blog's html form programmatically using Java

Tags: javascript, java, html

I am trying to submit a website's form using Java HttpClient.
Below is the code of html form :

```
 <form action="http://bmlaps.org/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform" class="comment-form" novalidate>

     <input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="" size="30" aria-required='true' required='required' />
     <input id="email" name="email" type="email" value="" size="30" aria-describedby="email-notes" aria-required='true' required='required' />
     <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-describedby="form-allowed-tags" aria-required="true" required="required"></textarea>

     <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Post Comment" />

 </form>
```

Below is my Java code :

```
public static void postForm() {
    String url = "someurl";

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("author", "testAuthor"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "testmail@gmail.com"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment", "test commment"));

    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity respEntity = response.getEntity();

        if (respEntity != null) {
            String content = EntityUtils.toString(respEntity);
            System.out.println(content);
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Could anybody help me on how to submit this form ?

Comment: I can make a second guess: you mistakenly think you're submitting the html form with this code and "url" contains the url of the html page with the form rather than the url where the data needs to be posted to.

Comment: @Gimby: Your second guess is right. Could you help me how to submit form. Sorry for not displaying the actual URL for security reasons. appreciate if you could help me with this code.

Comment: Probably if you put "http://bmlaps.org/wp-comments-post.php" in that url variable, it might already work. You're not submitting the form, you're simulating what the form does by manually posting data directly to the target url. If that isn't clear to you, you really need to re-read the documentation of HttpRequest.

Comment: @Gimby : It woked. Thanks a lot Gimby. You are right I was not submitting the form. Now I changed the url to form action url.

Comment: If you take a moment to think about it (who actually submits a HTML form? A: the browser. Is HttpClient a browser?) its not that hard to reason really ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple case of mistaken identity. The assumption in the code is that `HttpClient` will submit a form in a web page; hence the `url` variable contained the url of the webpage that holds the html form (the variable is masked out, but this was discussed in the comments).

But that is not how it works, you use HttpClient to emulate what the browser would do when submitting said form - which is to create a HTTP post request and transmit parameters as part of the data to a particular web url.

So in the `url` variable in the code, the url of the page where you submit **to** is placed, which is the same url as placed in the `action` attribute of the html form, and then the code works as expected.

Further reading: [the httpcomponents webpage](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/). Also do note that most Apache open source projects have a source distribution which holds many example programs / unit tests to demonstrate all the different features.

Comment: Thanks for more clarification. It worked when I changed the url.

Comment: @Peter if the answer is to your satisfaction, consider accepting it then